# Best way define a String constant used by a single method

Tags: java, constants

If I have a string constant that is used only by a single method, is it better to make it `static final`:

```
private static final String MY_CONST = "something";
```

or simply define it at the top of the method:

```
private void myMethod() {
    final String myConst = "something";
    // ... code that uses myConst a lot
}
```

or another way?

Comment: Does it matter though? Use whatever is most readable for you.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but personally, I would use the second way since it's only used in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use it directly in the method. Not only me actually, if we browse thru JDK code we will see lots of examle when many literals are used in a class and no one `static final` field is declared. Take a look at `java.io.DataInputStream`. JDK typically uses constant fields if a constant is supposed to be used in other classes, that is `public static final`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter either way, the only thing that matters is the readability to you. A good question to ask yourself is: which is easier for you to read and what makes more sense for you? Personally for me, I would use the second one, because it is only used in one method. However, if you are going to be changing the value a lot, then I would use the first one. But ultimately, it is totally up to you as the programmer and what makes more sense in your mind. I hope this gives you a better understanding.